# I'm confused about why pid isn't printed as expected in fork()

Tags: c

I'm currently learning System Programming course and I'm a little confused about how fork() works.

```
void fork0()
{
    int pid;
    if (pid = fork() == 0) {
        printf("c : %d\n", pid);
        printf("Hello from child\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        printf("p : %d\n", pid);
        printf("Hello from parent\n");
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

In this simple snippet of code, I get the following output :

```
p : 0
c : 1
Hello from child
Hello from parent
```

I thought `fork()` returns 0 to child process and the PID of child process to parent process.
But why does `printf()` inside the child process, print 'pid' 1? And why does `printf()` inside the parent process print 'pid' 0? I would appreciate any help.. thanks!!

Comment: `pid = fork() == 0` means `pid = (fork() == 0)` but you probably meant `(pid = fork()) == 0`

Comment: oh god.. thank you so much.. So it was not my misunderstanding of this topic!!

Comment: Where possible, use `int pid = fork(); if (pid < 0) { …handle error… } else if (pid == 0) { …be childish… } else { …be parental… }` — possibly using type `pid_t` instead of `int`.  That avoids the risk of mis-parenthesization (which my spell checker doesn't think is a word).  You could/should have combined each pair of `printf()` statements into one statement, too, and you could have added the result of `getpid()` to the outputs too.

Comment: The lesson here:  cramming assignments into `if ()` statements is a **bad idea** that leads to bug-prone code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, `==` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=` operator.

Therefore, `pid = fork() == 0` will assign the comparision result of `fork() == 0` to `pid`.

In the parent process, the return value of `fork()` won't be zero, so the comparision result to be assigned will be `0`.

Add parenthesis like `(pid = fork()) == 0` to firstly assign the return value of `fork()` to `pid` and then compare the value with zero.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I fully understood